# Perl Pattern Matching Question

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match patterns in perl and need some help.

I need to delete from a string anything that matches [xxxx] i.e. opening bracket-things inside it-first closing bracket that occurs.

So I am trying to substitute with space the opening bracket, things inside, first closing bracket with the following code :

```
   if($_ =~ /[/)
  {
    print "In here!\n";
    $_ =~ s/[(.*?)]/ /ig;
  }
```

Similarly I need to match  i.e. angular bracket-things inside it-first closing angular bracket.

I am doing that using the following code :

```
   if($_ =~ /</)
  {
    print "In here!\n";
    $_ =~ s/<(.*?)>/ /ig;
  }
```

This some how does not seem to work. My sample data is as below :

```
 'Joanne' <!--Her name does NOT contain "Kathleen"; see the section "Name"--> "'Jo'" 'Rowling', OBE [http://news bbc co uk/1/hi/uk/793844 stm Caine heads birthday honours list]  BBC News  17 June 2000  Retrieved 25 October 2000  , [http://content scholastic com/browse/contributor jsp?id=3578 JK Rowling Biography]  Scholastic com  Retrieved 20 October 2007  better known as 'J  K  Rowling' ,<ref name=telegraph>[http://www telegraph co uk/news/uknews/1531779/BBCs-secret-guide-to-avoid-tripping-over-your-tongue html Daily Telegraph, BBC's secret guide to avoid tripping over your tongue, 19 October 2006] is a British <!--do not change to "English" or "Scottish" until issue is resolved --> author best known as the creator of the [[Harry Potter]] fantasy series, the idea for which was conceived whilst on a train trip from Manchester to London in 1990  The Potter books have gained worldwide attention, won multiple awards, sold more than 400 million copies and been the basis for a popular series of films, in which Rowling had creative control serving as a producer in two of the seven installments  [http://www businesswire com/news/home/20100920005538/en/Warner-Bros -Pictures-Worldwide-Satellite-Trailer-Debut%C2%A0Harry Business Wire - Warner Bros  Pictures mentions J  K  Rowling as producer ]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_ =~ /someregex/` will not modify `$_`

Just a note, `$_ =~ /someregex/` and `/someregex/` do the same thing.

Also, you don't need to check for the existence of [ or < or the grouping parenthesis:

`s/\[.*?\]/ /g;`

s/<.*?>/ /g;

will do the job you want.

Edit: changed code to match the fact you're modifying $_

Comment: I’m confused.  Which of those substitutions are you saying does what?

Comment: Note that the ? is important. It tells Perl not to do greedy matching. Otherwise, you'll match "[asfs [safs] asfsd]"

Comment: @tchrist His original code was trying to remove both [...] and <...>.  Line 1 removes [...] and line 2 removes <...>.

Comment: @mmccoo The current code will match "[asfs [safs]" from your example, leaving "asfsd]".  Which is probably not desired, but that construct wasn't included in the example data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this:

```
1 while s/\[[^\[\]]*\];
```

Demo:

```
% echo "i have [some [square] brackets] in [here] and [here] today."| perl -pe '1 while s/\[[^\[\]]*\]/NADA/g'
i have NADA in NADA and NADA today.
```

Versus the failing:

```
% echo "i have [some [square] brackets] in [here] and [here] today." | perl -pe 's/\[.*?\]/NADA/g'
i have NADA brackets] in NADA and NADA today.
```

The recursive regular expression I leave as an exercise for the reader. :)

---

**EDIT:** [Eric Strom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189416/eric-strom) kindly provided a recursive solution you don’t have to use `1 while`:

```
% echo "i have [some [square] brackets] in [here] and [here] today." | perl -pe 's/\[(?:[^\[\]]*|(?R))*\]/NADA/g'
i have NADA in NADA and NADA today.
```

Comment: `s/\\[(?:[^\\[\\]]*|(?R))*\\]/NADA/g`

Answer (score 1):

- Square brackets have special meaning in the regex syntax, so escape them: `/\[.*?\]/`. (You also don't need the parentheses here, and doing case-insensitive matching is pointless.)
- It's been a long time since I had to wrestle with Perl, but I'm pretty sure that testing $_ with a regex will also modify $_ (even if you aren't using s///). You don't need the test anyway; just run the replacement, and if the pattern doesn't match anywhere, then it won't do anything.

Comment: A pattern match operation does not modify the string matched against. If it did, you couldn’t match constants, but you can: `"REPORT" =~ /^\Q$choice/i`.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to modify the string *per se*, but rather to report success or failure on $_ and thus overwrite the $_ that was provided for matching.

Comment: the `m//` operator never writes to `$_`.  it will return true or false in scalar context, and the matched groups in list context.  the numeric match variables `$1, $2, $3 ...` will be set to the corresponding matched groups.

Comment: Thanks; I knew there was a reason I wasn't completely sure. :)